# Ils ont passé de bonnes vacances bien qu'il pleuve/ait plu

Tags: subjonctif, passé-composé, imparfait

Bonjour !
En se référant au passé peut-on mettre dans cette phrase le subjonctif présent ? (Je suis conscient que l'imparfait du subjonctif est tombé en désuétude.)

Ils **ont passé** de bonnes vacances bien qu'il *pleuve/ait plu*.

Ils **passaient** de bonnes vacances bien qu'il *pleuve/ait plu*.

Comment interpréter ces deux phrases ? Sont-elles correctes ?

Merci d'avance :)

Comment: Le problème ici n'est pas l'emploi du subjonctif mais le choix de l'imparfait ou du passé composé.  Les deux n'ont pas la même valeur, il faut plus de contexte pour savoir lequel employer. Le passé composé appelle le subjonctif passé  dans la première. Dans la deuxième *bien que* après une principale à l'imparfait  ne me semble pas compatible. Personnellement je n'emploierais pas le subjonctif dans la première non plus. « Ils ont passé de bonnes vacances malgré la pluie » semble plus idiomatique.

Comment: Ils ont passé de bonnes vacances bien qu'il pleuvait.

Answer (score 4):

1. Ils ont passé de bonnes vacances bien qu'il pleuve.

   Possible mais n'a pas vraiment de sens. Il pleut aujourd'hui alors que leurs vacances sont terminées.
2. **Ils ont passé de bonnes vacances bien qu'il ait plu** (tous les jours).

   On rapporte des faits achevés. On sait que ces vacances sont terminées. Le subjonctif passé s'impose ici.
3. Ils passaient de bonnes vacances bien qu'il ait plu.

   On décrit une situation passée en train de se dérouler. Le subjonctif passé n'est pas exclu ici mais signifierait qu'il avait cessé de pleuvoir au moment où la scène qu'on décrit se déroule, ce qui n'est probablement pas le sens attendu.
4. Ils passaient de bonnes vacances bien qu'il pleuve.

   On décrit une situation passée en train de se dérouler. Le présent peut être considéré comme intemporel, proche du présent de vérité générale de l'indicatif, sauf que *bien que* impose le subjonctif. On peut renforcer cette idée de vérité générale (qui a beaucoup perdu de sa véracité ces dernières années) avec cette phrase: *Bien qu'il y pleuve, ils passaient de bonnes vacances en Bretagne.*

On peut s'affranchir de toutes ces interrogations à propos des temps et modes en utilisant ces formes :

5. **Ils ont passé de bonnes vacances malgré la pluie.**
6. **Ils passaient de bonnes vacances malgré la pluie.** (requiert un contexte)

Comment: L'imparfait ne me semble pas coller ici. On attend une justification de cet imparfait, *bien que* ne le justifie pas. Par ex. *Bien qu'il pleuve, ils passaient de bonnes vacances quand/lorsque le petit est tombé malade.* L'imparfait montre l'action en cours. Le passé composé montre l'action dans sa totalité, c.à.d. achevée.

Comment: @None Je ne serais pas aussi catégorique que toi. L'imparfait est quand même possible pour moi sans qu'on ait à le justifier dans la phrase même où il est employé.

Comment: Le plus évident me semble: Bien qu'il pleuvait,

Comment: https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/chroniq/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_titls&page=9U66xqoK0nJk.html

Comment: @None *Bien qu'il y pleuve, ils passaient de bonnes vacances en Bretagne.*

Comment: Il faudrait encore un peu plus de contexte. « Et tes parents ? » « Ils ont passé  de bonnes vacances bien qu'il ait plu ». On peut arrêter la conversation. ¶ Par contre : « Et tes parents ? » «  Bien qu'il ait plu ils passaient de bonnes vacance en Bretagne » pour moi la conversation n'est pas finie, j'attends une suite ...

Comment: @None Je vois plutôt *Bien qu'il pleuve, ils passaient de bonnes vacances* dans un récit qui décrit ces vacanciers. Bon, au moins on est d'accord pour trouver *malgré la pluie* plus simple.

Comment: Mais on est aussi d'accord sur le reste :  tu dis bien « dans un récit... », c.à.d. un **contexte** avant et/ou après. Alors qu'avec le passé composé la phrase se suffit à elle seule !